# "Get-WMIObject Win32_CDROMdrive | Select MediaLoaded" tells me if there's a CD loaded into my CD drive

Tags: powershell, boolean

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_CDROMdrive | Select MediaLoaded
```

does a great job of telling me if there's a CD loaded into my CD drive.     It returns this:

```
MediaLoaded
-----------
       True
```

My problem is:  I can't figure out how to evaluate this output as boolean "True" or "False".  It always seems to be "True" even when the return text says "False".

Answer (score 3):

You don't expand the property, so your `Select-Object` command gives you an object with one property with a boolean value instead of the actual boolean value. Since PowerShell [interprets non-empty/non-zero values as `$true`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) you're getting the behavior you observed when you use the object in a boolean context.

Change this:

```
... | Select MediaLoaded
```

into this:

```
... | Select -Expand MediaLoaded
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!  That allows a Boolean analysis.